# Can't install VS Code after changing username and user directory name

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have changed my C drive name to a new name **(*C:\users{oldName} => C:\users{newName}***)
then I noticed that vs code is broken.
So, I tried to do fresh install of vs code. I deleted all the related files of vs code then run .exe file of it.
but it gives this error:
**[*Setup was unable to create directory "C:\users{oldName}",*
*Error 5: access is denied*.**]

**How can I fix it ?? Please help!!**

I tried after changing the environments varibles but the installation of vs code didn't happen.

Comment: [See this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-5-access-denied-setup-unable-to-create-the/e9e9ad9b-9a81-4a99-962e-3e5f0708a855)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the result of improper uninstallation of VS Code. This helped : https://superuser.com/a/1704064, remove this registry key : `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{771FD6B0-FA20-440A-A002-3B3BAC16DC50}_is1`

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall VS Code, In Windows it will throw error (Refer a screenshot) while trying to uninstall it from 'Add or Remove Programs'.

[image]

But while throwing error it will show you location of uninstaller utility. Simply go there , click on it and uninstall. Now install a fresh VS code from wherever you prefer. I would suggest do it from Microsoft store.